# Как сделать отступы слева и справа от границ окна - Swing Java

Tags: java, swing

Месяц только изучаю JAVA. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как мне сделать отступы слева и справа, чтобы элементы например на 10 пикселей сдвинулись ближе к середине.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Прикладываю свой код:

```
package СurrencyСonverter;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

public class CurrencyWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    String[] currency = {"Российский рубль (RUB)","Евро (EUR)","Доллар (USD)",
            "Фунт стерлингов (GBR)","Индийская рупия (INR)","Тайский бат (THB)","Канадский доллар (CAD)"};

    double[][] coefficient={
            {1,0.01359,0.15887,0.012076,1.09,0.53,0.020849},
            {73.58,1,1.17,0.89,80.62,38.97,1.53},
            {62.94,0.85,1,0.76,68.75,33.27,1.31},
            {82.81,1.13,1.32,1,90.44,43.77,1.73},
            {0.92,0.0012,0.14,0.011,1,0.48,0.019},
            {1.89,0.025,0.03,0.022,2.07,1,0.03944},
            {47.96,0.65,0.76,0.58,52.39,25.35,1}
    };

    int currency1,currency2;
    double amount1, amount2;

    JPanel pan1 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan2 = new JPanel();
    JPanel pan3 = new JPanel();

    JLabel lbl_11 = new JLabel("Выберите валюту №1");
    JLabel lbl_12 = new JLabel("Введите сумму №1");
    JLabel lbl_21 = new JLabel("Выберите валюту №2");
    JLabel lbl_22 = new JLabel("Итоговая сумма");

    JComboBox<String> box1= new JComboBox<String>(currency);
    JComboBox<String> box2= new JComboBox<String>(currency);

    JTextField txt1 = new JTextField(20);
    JTextField txt2 = new JTextField(20);

    JButton btn = new JButton("Рассчитать");

    public CurrencyWindow() {

        super("Конвертер Валют");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setResizable(true);
        setSize(550,250);



        pan1.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));
        pan2.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,1));

        pan1.add(lbl_11);
        pan1.add(box1);
        pan1.add(lbl_12);
        pan1.add(txt1);

        pan2.add(lbl_21);
        pan2.add(box2);
        pan2.add(lbl_22);
        pan2.add(txt2);

        add(pan1,BorderLayout.WEST);
        add(pan2,BorderLayout.EAST);

        pan3.add(btn);
        add(pan3,BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        btn.addActionListener(this);


        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        if(e.getSource()==btn){
            try{
                amount1= Integer.parseInt(txt1.getText());
                currency1=box1.getSelectedIndex();
                currency2=box2.getSelectedIndex();
                amount2=amount1*coefficient[currency1][currency2];
                txt2.setText(Double.toString(amount2));
            }catch (NumberFormatException ex){
                txt2.setText("В поле слева нужно вводить число!");
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Заранее благодарю.

Answer (score 3):

```
public CurrencyWindow() {
    super("Конвертер Валют");

    setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setResizable(true);
    setSize(550,250);

    getRootPane().setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 10, 0, 10));

    ...
}
```